# Row manipulation for Dataframe in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe in spark which is like :

```
 column_A | column_B
 ---------  --------
  1          1,12,21
  2          6,9
```

both `column_A` and `column_B` is of String type.

how can I convert the above dataframe  to a new dataframe which is like :

```
  colum_new_A | column_new_B
  -----------   ------------
     1             1
     1             12
     1             21
     2             6
     2             9
```

both `column_new_A` and `column_new_B` should be of String type.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `split` the `Column_B` with `comma` and use the `explode` function as

```
val df = Seq(
  ("1", "1,12,21"),
  ("2", "6,9")
).toDF("column_A", "column_B")
```

You can use `withColumn` or `select` to create new `column`.

```
df.withColumn("column_B", explode(split( $"column_B", ","))).show(false)

df.select($"column_A".as("column_new_A"), explode(split( $"column_B", ",")).as("column_new_B"))
```

Output:

```
+------------+------------+
|column_new_A|column_new_B|
+------------+------------+
|1           |1           |
|1           |12          |
|1           |21          |
|2           |6           |
|2           |9           |
+------------+------------+
```